# Can't get Google Chrome to X11 forward but Firefox does

Tags: xorg, google-chrome, x11-forwarding

So after much trial and error I have managed to get X11 forwarding work. My desktop in the office is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I use XQuartz to ssh in from my MacBook Pro. When I ssh in, I get the following on the terminal:

```
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-128-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
```

I know the X11 forwarding is working because I can get FireFox to forward, but its extremely slow and buggy.

[image: Firefox forwards]

But I cannot get Google Chrome to forward. The terminal gives the following on running the command `google-chrome`:

```
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[10497:10497:0702/053002.891053:ERROR:gl_context_glx.cc(227)] Couldn't make context current with X drawable.
[10497:10497:0702/053002.891090:ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(63)] gl::GLContext::MakeCurrent() failed
[10455:10549:0702/053003.740008:ERROR:bus.cc(394)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
```

and XQuartz just displays a blank window. On `ctrl-c`ing the process and exiting the terminal further spews more error messages (which I can post if required). But can someone help me out and tell me what I am doing wrong or if I have not got x11 forwarding set up properly? I basically followed the procedure [here](http://dasunhegoda.com/gui-ubuntu-server-x11-forwarding/679/) (also `xauth` was already installed for me) so I just edited the configuration files.

Comment: For me, even Chromium works, as well as literally every other software I've tried, only Google Chrome doesn't work. The `--disable-gpu` flag did not help for me.

Answer (score 7):

Try starting Chrome using its [SwiftShader](https://swiftshader.googlesource.com/SwiftShader) software renderer - which was [integrated into Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=630728) in 2017:

```
chromium-browser --use-gl=swiftshader
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 this worked for me using google-chrome command; while --disable-gpu didn't

Comment: On RHEL 7 this worked for me using google-chrome command; while --disable-gpu didn't

Answer (score 5):

Chrome has hardware acceleration turned on by default, and I think this is causing you the issue. Try starting it with:

```
google-chrome --disable-gpu
```

Comment: Are you saying we should disable hardware acceleration on Chrome browser on client side or server side?

Comment: This flag should be passed to the server side, since Chrome is running on the server and is forwarded via X11

Answer (score 1):

Are you using SNAP for Chrome but not Firefox?

If xeyes/xlogo/xterm works but not chrome make sure if it's from snap.

If it is it needs this one in .bashrc:

```
export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority
```

See more information https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/x11-forwarding-using-ssh/2381

Thanks https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/709789/12207